# with angular cli the project stop at 10% building modules 3/3 modules 0 active

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, build, angular-cli

after giving the ng command serve the build of the project it stops at 10% after which it compiles without giving errors open localhost: 4200 I only get a blank page. I tried to create a new project by typing ng new my-app from the command line, even here the build stops at 10% but at least the initial page of the default program can be seen.

i tried to create a new project by typing ng new my-app from the command line, even here the build stops at 10% but at least the initial page of the default program can be seen.I tried to reinstall angular, nodejs etc. but nothing has changed. I use windows 10.

my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "smart-box",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
   "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/core": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/router": "^8.2.3",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.2",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "webpack": "^4.39.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.802.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
   "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^8.9.5",
    "@types/webpack-env": "^1.14.0",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
"jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
"karma": "~4.1.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
"karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
"protractor": "~5.4.0",
"ts-node": "~7.0.0",
"tslint": "~5.15.0",
"typescript": "^3.5.3"
  }
}
```

other information:

```
Angular CLI: 8.2.2
Node: 10.16.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 8.2.3
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... platform-server, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.802.2
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.802.2
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.802.2
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.802.2
@angular-devkit/core              8.2.2
@angular-devkit/schematics        8.2.2
@angular/cli                      8.2.2
@angular/http                     7.2.15
@ngtools/webpack                  8.2.2
@schematics/angular               8.2.2
@schematics/update                0.802.2
rxjs                              6.4.0
typescript                        3.5.3
webpack                           4.39.2
```

Comment: checkout your console and lemme know if there is any error

Comment: the console is ok

Comment: was it ever work on your pc before?

Comment: yes both my project and the default project and the build was 100%

Comment: @matteo how did you resolve this issue. I am getting same issue. Please help